# batch file run in task schedule not work

Tags: batch-file, scheduled-tasks

hello i try to create script batch file for checking the previous mouth folder and delete that folder, when i run by double click it run perfectly and can delete folder, but when i try it run on task schedule it show run complete but it do not anything, here is my code

```
@Echo Off & SetLocal
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

REM ////////////getpreviousmouth//////////////
for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime /value') do set 
"dt=%%a"
set "YY=%dt:~2,2%" & set "YYYY=%dt:~0,4%" & set "MM=%dt:~4,2%" & set 
"DD=%dt:~6,2%"
set "HH=%dt:~8,2%" & set "Min=%dt:~10,2%" & set "Sec=%dt:~12,2%"
set "previousdate=%YYYY%_%MM%_%DD%" & set "timestamp=%HH%%Min%%Sec%"
set "fullstamp=%YYYY%-%MM%-%DD%_%HH%-%Min%-%Sec%"
For /F %%A In ('WMIc OS Get LocalDateTime') Do For %%B In (%%A) Do Set _=%%B
Set "YYYY=%_:~,4%" & Set "MM=%_:~4,2%" & Set "DD=%dt:~6,2%"
If %MM% Equ 01 (Set/A "YYYY-=1" & Set "MM=12") Else (Set/A "MM=1%MM%-1"
Call Set "MM=%%MM:~-2%%")
set "previousdate=%YYYY%-%MM%"

REM ////////////delete folder data in previousmouth//////////////
set pathdata=D:\Backup\InteractiveBackendDB_BK
CD %pathdata%
for /D %%A IN (%previousdate%"*") DO  (
set pathfolders=%%A
set pathfolder=!pathfolders:~0,-3!
if !pathfolder!==%previousdate% (
    echo  !pathdata!\!pathfolders!
    rd /s /q !pathdata!\!pathfolders!
)
 timeout 10
)
```

Comment: The script doesn't happen to be located on your D: drive, does it?

Comment: it working all of this script when i execute by click double-click, but when i use this script in task schedule it not work.

Comment: use `cd /d` to actually switch to another drive. What kind of drive is `D:`? Is it a network resource?

Comment: Yes drive is D: in local computer

Comment: i try to change to cd /d it work, thank you so much.